# Atom non composer PHP support

Tags: php, atom-editor

I've just started using [Atom](https://atom.io/). I am enjoying using it and allows me to add plenty of additional packages.

I have several projects that I'm working on that use composer and a PSR-0 autoloader. These projects work fine and I am able to shift+alt click the method names and it takes me through to the correct methods, this was achieved using the atom-autocomplete-php package and some minor config changes.

I also have several older projects, some in PHP4 (yes very old I know!) and several in CodeIgniter. I would like to be able to have autocomplete and to be able to click through methods/functions on these projects. I cannot seem to find a package that will provide me the functionality to achieve this and I just want to know if anyone else has found a package that will provide this functionality.

I have tried searching on Google but I can't see anything relevant, any help with this would be greatly received.

Thanks

Comment: I did sort of find a solutions for this. You need to implement ctags which will scan all your codebase and keep some map files which it will use to locate functions and classes. If anyone has a better solution let me know.